# How can an extensible interface in TypeScript adapt to the needs of both the codebase and the user?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently facing a difficult problem. I've designed a library using TypeScript. In this library, there's an interface called EmitterMap. I'm hoping to utilize TypeScript's interface merging mechanism to allow users to expand this interface on their own. In order to avoid any conflicts with the users' actual definitions, I've defined EmitterMap in this library as an empty interface, leaving the specific content entirely up to the user.

```js
// This is an empty interface defined in the library.
interface EmitterMap{}
```

Here's the content that the user can extend.

```js
declare module "my-module"{
    interface EmitterMap{
        abc: string;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm encountering now is that, while this design has been very smooth for users, if I infer the types of the EmitterMap interface while writing the library, some type errors may occur. For instance, if I make the following type inference.

```js
function sender<const T extends keyof EmitterMap | ( keyof EmitterMap )[]>
(
    event_names: T,
    data: T extends keyof EmitterMap ? EmitterMap [T] : EmitterMap[T[number]]
)
{

}
```

The type EmitterMap[T[number]] will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another nested [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to ensure that your generic argument `keyof EmitterMap | (keyof EmitterMap)[]` can lookup a `EmitterMap` value.

```
interface EmitterMap {
  key1: "value1";
  key2: "value2";
  key3: "value3";
}

declare function sender<
  const K extends keyof EmitterMap | (keyof EmitterMap)[],
>(
  event_names: K,
  data: K extends (infer U extends keyof EmitterMap)[]
    ? EmitterMap[U]
    : K extends keyof EmitterMap
    ? EmitterMap[K]
    : never,
): void;

const result1 = sender("key1", "value1");
const result2 = sender(["key1", "key2"], "value2");
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFthklAsnAB2QG8AoZZAawgE8BGALmQCIA3OAGwFcI7mBuclVoAmJm048RAodRoBmce24R5MgL6lSAEwgIOcKChhcQCMMAD2IZAGcIIXVAA8QhNdthkAaWQQAHpCOtsI0ljBomNjQ+EQAPsgAFHLhkVg4sQCUANoAugA0pAB8iUIQrA5gAPogcOgQtkzehRTacGBwTX6BDtohiaAw0MgAqt1BfaGpGOkxhDm5QhQA-GnReITZI4sUFF0BEyEpETPrsUvIq6cZm947u0wg5dCFmUyslsDagqTuIJ7IIy2LgcMB0ZAAXjsvWgiWYcj4+RYyh4fEygj+AKBILAIkh0McsOy8NoiJYcmkBWRkgg0nRpCAA)